# How to I start a group of jobs on an SGE grid that will all start at the same time?

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am using a tool which spawns parallel jobs onto an SGE grid.  When the grid is close to capacity some of the grid jobs start but others do not.  This leads to wildly different results from the tool depending on the actual number of jobs that start.

So how can I get SGE to queue until all the grid slots are available and then start all the jobs at once?

Note that the grid slots will typically become available across a number of machines.

Answer (score 1):

From the `qsub` man page:

```
  -tcon y[es]|n[o]
       Available for qsub only.

       Can be used in conjunction with array jobs (see -t option) to 
       submit a concurrent array job.

       For a concurrent array job either all tasks can be started in one
       scheduling run or the whole job will stay pending.
```

Include this in your job script with

```
#$ -tcon y
```